# Get only value in dictionary if len == 1

Tags: python, coding-style

Is there better way of getting the single value in the dictionary, if my dictionary only has one element?

I'm currently doing `if len(a) == 1: print a.values()[0]`, is this the pythonic way to do it?

Comment: It's suspect that you'd need this in the first place. What is your use case?

Comment: The Pythonic way would be not to do it, because this is not how you use a dictionary

Comment: @NiklasB. Well the case is that i'm iterating over an excel sheet and adding matches to a dictionary with ``dictionary and[matchedcellcontent] = column``. I use the keys to create buttons for the user to select which match (column) to use. Therefore it's easier for the user if there is only one match, then use it without a selection-GUI

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is `print(next(iter(a)))`, not sure if it's better.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do... but if you have a button for each element in the dictionary, why not something like `for cellcontent, column in a.items(): make_button(name=cellcontent, use_column=column)`?

Comment: in future, you should put a "big picture" into your question, as it will help guide the answers. also - the rest of your code, if you are getting one value left as a final check and previously you were checking if there are two answers left.. would change the whole code. please add more information.

Comment: @InbarRose, Well the problem with doing that is that there are a lot of sensitive information in the code, and I would have to change alot of the code in order to post it, but sure I'll get better on it.
 chase:, I could do that, but if there's only one element I don't want a button since there is only one choise.

Comment: @Vixen: If you don't need the association, just use a list of tuples and then use `lst[0]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no better way to do it, it should work fine

Comment: That's not true, when you use '.values()' in a dict python returns a dict_values object, and dict_values object is not subscriptable.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of style, you should treat all dictionaries and lists as if they have multiple entries.

```
di={1:'one'}
for e in sorted(di):
    print di[e]
```

If you KNOW you are dealing with a data structure that will (or should) only have one element or the position of the elements is the most crucial thing, use a different structure. In Python, use a tuple.

Comment: The OP already acknowledged that tuple is the correct data tuple for his problem. +1

Comment: I don't KNOW that there will be only one element in it. There can be 0 (error in my point of view), 1 (No button generation), >=2 (create >=2 choises). so list of tuples is fine in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dict like this:

```
nice_dict = {'name': 'rodrigo'}
```

A dict with only one key and wanna the value you can do something like this:

```
def get_single_element_dict_value(single_ement_dict):
    return list(single_element_dict.values())[0]
```

I think this is a good approach.